# Gradle build fails during test in GitHub workflow, runs successfully on IntelliJ though

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, github-actions, gradle-plugin

If I run just 'gradle build -x test' it runs without error but fails when with test option. It works fine if run locally with IntelliJ.

These are few errors and warning I see in GitHub actions log:

1. Cannot infer source root(s) for source `file '/home/runner/work/idau/idau/src/main/java/se/web/ErrorDto.java'`. Supported types are `File` (directories only), `DirectoryTree` and `SourceDirectorySet`
2. Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file
3. : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@7accf242] to prepare test instance [se.ConfigTest@6297b4ce]
   3905

3906
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

To me it seems issue with env and some plugin but unable pin point that. Tried removing cache and cleaning but did not work out. Posting it here as I haven't find any answer yet.

Here is my workflow script:
steps:

```
  - name: Checkout
    id: step1
    uses: actions/checkout@master
    # with:
      # ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
      # repository: ${{github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name }}
  
  # Setup JAVA with specific version
  - name: Set up JDK 8
    uses: actions/setup-java@v3
    with:
      cache: gradle
      java-version: '8'
      distribution: 'adopt'
  
  # Setup Gradle with specific version
  - name: Setup Gradle
    uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2.3.3
    with:
      gradle-version: 4.10.1
  
 
  - name: Start PostgreSQL on Ubuntu
    run: |
      sudo systemctl start postgresql.service
      pg_isready

  # Create a DB user as per 
  - name: Create additional user
    run: |
      chmod og+X /home/runner/
      sudo -u postgres psql --command="CREATE USER *** PASSWORD '****';" --command="\du"

  # Create database
  - name: Create additional database
    run: |
      sudo -u postgres createdb *** --owner=***;
      sudo -u postgres createdb *** --owner=***;
      sudo -u postgres psql --command="\l"

  # This user is needed as defined in build.gradle
  #invalidating the cache
  - name: Add git user details and perform gradle prerequisite 
    run: | 
        git config --global user.email "${GITHUB_ACTOR}"
        git config --global user.name "${GITHUB_ACTOR}@users.noreply.github.com"
        echo "current user: ${GITHUB_ACTOR}"
        # echo "remove .gradle and generated folder: $(rm -rf .gradle generated)"
        # echo "remove all cached .gradle folder: $(rm -rf ~/.gradle)"
        # echo "give full rights to gradlew : $(chmod +x ./gradlew)"
        
        echo "gradle version: $(gradle -version)"

  - run: gradle clean assemble
  - name: Validate Gradle wrapper
    uses: gradle/wrapper-validation-action@v1

  
  # --no-daemon Ensure no Gradle daemons are running anymore when your workflow completes.
  - name: Build with Gradle
    id: build
    uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2.3.3
    with:
      gradle-version: 4.10.1
      arguments: build --info --no-daemon
      
  
  - run: ls -R
 
  - name: Upload build reports
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
    if: success() || failure()
    with:
      name: build-reports
      path: ./build/reports/
```

Comment: If you need test, keep it, if you don't delete test folder completely.

Comment: do you mean to delete the test folder generated after build explicitly?

Comment: It got resolved by fixing the test cases and passing spring.config location argument with build like build -Dspring.config.location=classpath/config/local/.
But now failing with this error:
testCreateAndApproveSwishPayment FAILED
230
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException at RefundServiceTests.java:663
231
        Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException at RefundServiceTests.java:663
232
2023-02-16 09:01:22.821  INFO 2118 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown initiated...

Comment: Yes, delete test folder, clear maven, then run the app, after that let us know what happened?

Comment: It worked. not exactly the same way but by manually performing the cleanup instead of following gradle clean command. Thanks Amir.